# Can you use an <a> tag as the submit button in a formik form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, formik

I currently have a form:

```js
<Formik
      onSubmit={async (values) => {
        await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 500));
        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      }}
      initialValues={{
        yourName: "",
        yourEmail: "",
        yourTel: "",
        yourMessage: "",
      }}
    >
      <Form>
        <Field name="yourName" placeholder="Name" />
        <ErrorMessage name="yourName" component="div" />
        <Field name="yourEmail" placeholder="Email" type="email" />
        <ErrorMessage name="yourEmail" component="div" />
        <Field name="yourTel" placeholder="Phone Number" />
        <ErrorMessage name="yourTel" component="div" />
        <Field name="yourMessage" as="textarea" placeholder="Message..." />
        <ErrorMessage name="yourMessage" component="div" />
        <button>
          Submit
        </button>
      </Form>
    </Formik>
```

However, I would like to use an `<a></a>` tag to submit the form.

I have tried doing

```html
<a type='submit'>Submit</a>

and

<a onClick={() => {submitForm()}}>Submit</a>
```

but neither work.

I wondering if there is a way of doing this, and if so, how?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to use `a` tag for submitting the form?

Comment: you need to set a ref to the form and then on that onClick you will use that ref to submit the form.

Comment: @Mina I have styled an `a` tag for buttons and it would be more convenient to use, it's not essential, I was just wondering if it could be done

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can use formik render prop

```
<Formik
      onSubmit={async (values) => {
        await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 500));
        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      }}
      initialValues={{
        yourName: "",
        yourEmail: "",
        yourTel: "",
        yourMessage: "",
      }}
      render={({ values, handleSubmit }) => {
          return (
             <Form>
                ...
                <a onClick={handleSubmit}>
                   Submit
                </a>
             </Form>
          );
      }}

/>
```